# how to call drawrect method from another class when it is made in appdelegate class

Tags: objective-c, xcode, drawrect, cgrect

I have made a method in appdelegate class which is-

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (category)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
       UIImage *img = [UIImage newImageFromResource:@"Img.png"];
       [img drawInRect:rect];
       [img release];
}
@end
```

I want to set the size(x,y,width,height) of the image(Img.png) programitcally in some other class..so how to call/use (- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect) method in some other class?

Comment: You can't use this to draw a custom navigation bar as of iOS 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like this

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate drawRect:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];
```

Comment: Huh no. First off, you are not supposed to call `drawRect:` at all. Second, `appDelegate` doesn't `respondToSelector` `drawRect:`: `drawRect:` is defined in a category to the `UINavigationBar` class